# How do I write the cmake script for clion to include glfw?

Tags: linux, cmake, clion, glfw

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(hello)
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_search_module(GLFW REQUIRED glfw3)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_executable(hello main.cpp)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIRS})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(hello ${GLFW_STATIC_LIBRARIES})
```

It tells me

```
CMake Error at /home/user/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/CLion/ch-0/193.5233.144/bin/cmake/linux/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:696 (message):
  None of the required 'glfw3' found
```

when I try to build it. My glfw folder is located at `/usr/local/include/GLFW`.

Comment: Using `pkg-config` implies that you have `glfw3.pc` file. Do you have the one?

Comment: AFAIK glfw3 is using cmake as build system
src: https://packages.debian.org/fr/sid/amd64/libglfw3-dev/filelist so you can use
find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED)
...
target_link_libraries(Foo glfw)

Comment: @Tsyvarev yeah it's located at `/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig/glfw3.pc`

Comment: @Mizux thanks yeah that solved it. I'm still a noob with cmake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, glfw3 is using CMake as the build system,
(src: `packages.debian.org/fr/sid/amd64/libglfw3-dev/filelist`)
which uses modern CMake, so you don't need `GLFW_INCLUDE_DIRS` etc...

Inside this file `/usr/lib/cmake/glfw3/glfw3Targets.cmake` (loaded by `/usr/lib/cmake/glfw3/glfw3Config.cmake`), you'll see:

```
...
# Create imported target glfw
add_library(glfw SHARED IMPORTED)

set_target_properties(glfw PROPERTIES
  INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "GLFW_DLL"
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "/usr/include"
)
...
```

So you can simply use:

```
find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED)
...
target_link_libraries(Foo glfw)
```

ps: same as my previous comment